# Get AD users in sharepoint people picker

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, people-picker, people-search

I want to fetch the AD group users in SharePoint. Below is the code where i can get the SharePoint group. but how can we get AD group

```
 private SPFieldUserValueCollection GetPeopleFromPickerControl(PeopleEditor people, SPWeb web)
        {
            SPFieldUserValueCollection values = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();
            if (people.ResolvedEntities.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < people.ResolvedEntities.Count; i++)
                {
                    PickerEntity user = (PickerEntity)people.ResolvedEntities[i];
                    switch ((string)user.EntityData["PrincipalType"])
                    {
                        case "User":
                            SPUser webUser = web.EnsureUser(user.Key);
                            SPFieldUserValue userValue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, webUser.ID, webUser.Name);
                            values.Add(userValue);
                            break;

                        case "SharePointGroup":
                            SPGroup siteGroup = web.SiteGroups[user.EntityData["AccountName"].ToString()];
                            SPFieldUserValue groupValue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, siteGroup.ID, siteGroup.Name);
                            values.Add(groupValue);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return values;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

An AD Group is actually just another type of SPUser object. The SPUser object has the property IsDomainGroup which will be set to true if it is an AD group.